# Apply locally committed changes over pulled changes using source tree and git

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree, git-commit, git-checkout

I have a serious problem, I committed my local changes to the local branch. Then, I did a pull from the remote server. I then resolved the conflict. But, one mistake I did was, I accidentally accepted the change of the remote server over mine. So now, all my changes are gone. Luckily, I still have that local commit with my changes.

Now, I want my local commit to overwrite my pulled file. I am not sure what is the right way to do this on sourcetree. I can also try the command line on sourcetree. I have tried to checkout a branch on my local change/commit and marked it to track the remote branch. But that is not over writing it with my committed file. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to blow away your messed up local branch that has origin merged in you can.

`git reset --hard goodLocalCommitHash`

This will remove all commits on top of of the `goodLocalCommitHash` in your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not pushed the merge commit, and have not made any commits since the merge commit, `git reset --hard head~` will undo the merge, and then you can merge again. Otherwise, your safest bet is probably `git checkout <commit> <filename>`, which will overwrite  in your working directory with the version from . Then, simply commit that file.